# How can I create a gradient overlay in a scrolling container?

Tags: css, sass, linear-gradients

I have an overlay over a scrollable container.
When I scroll it seems to stick to the content within it.
How can I keep the gradient at the bottom of the element?

```
.content__conatiner {
             position: relative
             height: 500px;
}

.content__container:after {
            content: " ";
             position: absolute;
             left: 0;
             right: 0;
             bottom: 0;
             top: 0;
             background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
             /* FF3.6+ */

             background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
             /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

             background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
             /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

             background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
             /* Opera 11.10+ */

             background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
             /* IE10+ */

             background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
             /* W3C */
        }
```

[image]

example:   https://codepen.io/hellojessicagraham/pen/jpepMv

Comment: can you provide its fiddle?

Comment: https://codepen.io/hellojessicagraham/pen/jpepMv @YashwardhanPauranik

Comment: When div scroll, do you want ALWAYS see that gradient at the bottom during the scroll or do you want put that gradient at the bottom so you can see it only when you reach the div's bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another container to the main one and make the pseudo-element postioned relatively to it (move the `position:relative`)

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
div.container {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
div.box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.box p {
  color: white;
}

div.box:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events:none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(137, 255, 241, 0) 0%, black 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus.
      In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer
      vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla
      mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam
      quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus.
      In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat
      volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel
      leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius
      semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra
      vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero.
      Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam
      erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla
      vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius
      semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra
      vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero.
      Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam
      erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla
      vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius
      semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero. Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra
      vitae, orci.Etiam quis quam. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Maecenas libero.
      Duis risus. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```